# Raspberry Pi is constantly CPU throttling

Tags: pi-4, temperature, cpu

My Raspberry Pi 4, with heatsinks and 5v fan is idling at above 85 degrees Celsius constantly! Once I was simply updating via apt-get while doing other things and it ejected the SD Card as to try to not corrupt the files on it. I can only use my Pi safely with a huge fan right next to the naked Pi. Any help?

PS: Turns out vcgencmd measure_temp returns GPU temperature (or I think so). Any help?

Comment: Do you have anything connected to the pi that draws current?

Comment: @SimSon Keyboard, mouse, hdmi0, and power supply. Only thing open on it  was terminal.

Comment: If it gets that hot without relevant load (maybe detach everything for a test) then I'd say, your Pi is at least partially destroyed. Maybe a broken GPIO is shorts Vcc to GND or sth like that. Is it a new Pi or does it have a history?

Comment: Is your Pi in a case? Does it have ventilation? What happens with a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS, fully updated?

Comment: Try running `top` to see if anything is using lots of cpu.

Comment: @SimSon yeah, it does have a bit of history. I think I may have used the GPIO pins without enough care and broke something. Anyways to check that?

Comment: @CoderMike With no case, it stills reaches 90 degrees celsius. It's only stable when a huge fan is pointed at it. I am going to reinstall the OS.

Comment: @Andrew I did that, but what is supposed to stand out?

Comment: Anything constantly at the top of the list with high CPU?  If so, that could well be driving the temperature up.  If not (and the clean OS still runs hot) I guess somethings shorted and running hot.

Comment: @Andrew The top command is the only thing taking CPU power, about 1% of it.